# Proof of equation $\ln y=-kt+c$ is same as $y=c*e^{-kt}$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I'm trying to prove that one is the same as the other :
$$\ln y = -kt+c$$  $$y=ce^{-kt}$$

Where **c** is undefined and **k** is defined constant. I got as far as:
$$y=e^{-kt+c}$$
So by what rule would **c** be multiplied by **e**? Could someone explain please?
Thank you.

Comment: $$e^a \cdot e^b = e^{a+b}$$
Thus, $e^{-kt+c} = e^{-kt} \cdot e^c$
Therefore your statement is only true if $e^c = c$

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Please use $ equation $, even in titles.

Comment: They are not quite equivalent. For example one cannot quite get $y=-5e^{-kt}$ from any (real) $\ln y=-kt+c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because they aren't! 
Usually, in the context of differential equations, the $A$ in 
$$
y=Ae^{-kt}
$$
Really is a more concise stand in for some exponentiated constant, in your case $e^c$, i.e.
$$
\ln(y)=-kt+c\Rightarrow y=e^{-kt+c}=e^ce^{-kt}\Rightarrow y=Ae^{-kt}
$$

You can view the $A$ as absorbing constants you are adding on.

Comment: Thank you. It was really the operation with the $e^{a+b} = e^{a}e^{b}$ that I was looking for. Completely blanked out on it.

Comment: @JekDenys no problem, I remember it confusing me when I first saw it too

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, but usually, when one is solving a differential equation (I can't imagine another instance where these two would be "equivalent" in some sense), one writes:

$$\ln y = -kt + c \\ y = e^{-kt + c} \\ y = e^c e^{-kt}$$

Now $e^c$ is just a constant, so we may have given $c$ the name $a$ and then we would let $c = e^a$, so that $y =c e^{-kt}$

Comment: It was part of the ODE example, yes. Thank you.